# How to get the dependency information about public static final fields

Tags: java, javac, jdeps

Though `jdeps` can be used to get the class level dependencies, considering follow case:

**A.java:**

```java
public class A {
    public static final int AA = 1;
}
```

**B.java**

```java
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(A.AA);
    }
}
```

In this case, when using `javac` to do the complilation. The `A.AA` in `B.java` will be directly replaced by constant `1`.

In this case, jdeps can not find that B actually depends on A. How to find the dependency information when it comes to this kind of public static final field accessing?